# How to delete old Facebook chats from both end?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-privacy, chat, delete

I know Facebook doesn't allow users to delete chats from both side after 10 minutes. But is there any way or workaround to delete or vanish my sent messages from my friends' side?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to report that chat as spam.

From [Facebook Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/messenger-app/867755949908034) - report a conversation as spam:

1. Open the conversation and click three vertical dots.
2. Click **Something's Wrong**.
3. Select **Other > Spam**.
4. Click **Send Feedback**.